# How to create legends with triangular end boxes in arcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, legend

I want my legend which is now in the form of the left bar in the following image, to be shown in the form of the bar in the right side.

I couldn't find anything related for arcGIS.

Does anyone know of something?

[image]

Comment: Are you talking about legend in the Layout or in the TOC?

Comment: In the layout. as you can see in the figure. to be added as a guide to my contoured map.

Comment: You could just add a triangle graphic marker with the drawing toolbar with the desired color/size and add it to the top and bottom of the legend patches.

Comment: Adding to what Chris R said, you can use the drawing toolbar to cover the top and bottom quadrangles with white rectangles and then draw new triangle shaped polygons in the right color over them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To keep the legend "live" (rather than drawing it as graphics), divide the Contours layer into 3 layers in your map. One layer is for values >=12 and will appear at the top of the legend, one is for values <= 1 and will appear at the bottom of the legend, and one is for the values in between. The "Top" and "Bottom" layers will have custom patches in the legend.

Custom patches are loaded to a Style using the "New Legend Patch Shape" command. This command must be added as a button to any toolbar before creating the patches. Use the steps below.

Click Customize > Customize Mode from the main menu. 
Click the Commands tab on the Customize dialog box. 
Scroll through the Categories list and click Page Layout. 
Scroll through the Commands list and click and drag the New Legend Patch Shape command to any toolbar.

To create a custom patch for the Top layer, draw a triangle pointing up as either a graphic element or a polygon in a feature class. While it is selected, click on your new button for the "New Legend Patch Shape" command. Make the correct selection in "Patch Shape", and turn off "Preserve Aspect Ratio". Save the patch by clicking on "Add to Stylesheet" and close. Rotate the selected element or polygon 180 degrees and repeat to get a custom patch for the Bottom layer.

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed explanation. But it is somehow rework to separate my data. Isn't any way that just like what we can do for unique values symbology to select different symbols, do simply the same for the top and bottom values in classified symbology?

Comment: Unfortunately, a legend item can only use a single patch. This is a built-in limitation of legend objects that you can't get around. I tend to jump through insane hoops like I described above to keep the legend "live", but the graphics alternatives described by Chris R and Nir above are common and perfectly reasonable.